# Unable to update the no of contacts field on account

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to update the no of contacts custom field on account after insert and after update on account but i don't see the field getting updated.

Here is my code///

```
    trigger updatenumberofcontacts on Account(after insert, after update) {
    list<account> acctlist= New list<account>();
    //Get related contacts for this account
    Map<Id,Account> acctsWithcontacts = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]);
    //Add contact for each account after each account record is created
    //create custom field on account
   list<account> acct =New List<account>([select id, name, No_of_Contacts__c from account where Id IN :Trigger.new]);
   For (account a:acct) {
   integer Noofcontacts = acctsWithcontacts.get(a.id).Contacts.size();
   system.debug('//////////////'+Noofcontacts);
   if (acctsWithcontacts.get(a.id).Contacts.size()>0)
  {
  a.No_of_Contacts__c= Noofcontacts;
  }
  ///acctlist.add(acct);    
  }
 //update a;
 }
```

Comment: Because the events are after insert and after update you need to use update statement to save your changes to database.

Comment: You can use before .

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, RSF is not possible in OOB SFDC Accounts -> Contacts. But, there is a point-and-click solution that avoids the need for triggers - [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries (DLRS)](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) - free, and available in GitHub.

This will handle Contact insertion, deletion, reparenting, and undeletion - which is what you need to count.

Comment: `after insert` is not needed because at insert no contacts will be associated to account.. and for update case you need to handle recursive update call or we can just use `before update`.... I think it would a better idea to have trigger on contact `after insert, after update` and `DLRS` is good suggestion..

Comment: @sfdcweb That is a nice catch :)